# .net MVC and url.Action with marging anonymous

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I try to marging 2 anonymous object and pass the result to urlHelper.action() method, but the result is wrong,

this is my code:

```
public static MvcHtmlString EditButton(this HtmlHelper helper, object routeValues = null, string text = "")
    {
        UrlHelper u = new UrlHelper(helper.ViewContext.RequestContext);

        routeValues = routeValues ?? new { };

        string returnUrl = (string)helper.ViewBag.returnUrl;

        if (false == string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
            routeValues = ButtonHelper.Merge(routeValues, new { returnUrl = returnUrl });

        var x = u.RouteUrl(new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues));
        string href = u.Action("Edit",new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues));//<--here I aspect that href=".../edit/123?returnUrl=...."
        text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) ? Resources.Commons.Edit : text;

        //        < a href = '@Url.Action("Edit", new { id = Model.Id })' class="btn btn-default">
        //    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> @Resources.Commons.Edit
        //</a>
        MvcHtmlString r = new MvcHtmlString(String.Format("<a href=\"{0}\" class=\"btn btn-default\">"
            + "<i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-pencil\"></i> {1}</a>", href, text));
        return r;
    }

    public static dynamic Merge(dynamic item1, dynamic item2)
    {
        var result = new ExpandoObject();
        var d = result as IDictionary<string, object>; //work with the Expando as a Dictionary

        foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo fi in item1.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            d[fi.Name] = fi.GetValue(item1, null);

        }
        foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo fi in item2.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            d[fi.Name] = fi.GetValue(item2, null);

        }

        return d;
```

}

what is wrong, I aspected that href variable like to: ".../edit/123?returnUrl=...."

Thank you
Regards

Comment: Why are you using `dynamic`? Just create a the `RouteValueDictionary` using `new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues)` and the use `.Add()` method to add the other key/value pairs

Comment: Because, this is a snipped code of my buttonhelper extension, item1 source is in my cshtml code and i don't know what contains

Comment: What do you mean you don't know what it contains? - You have assigned to to `string returnUrl`, But why are your using `@Html.EditButton( new { returnUrl = ViewBag.returnUrl, <other values> }, "xxx")`?

Comment: extension method editButton check if exist the property returnUrl into view bag if exist create a link with querystring parameter ?returUrl=...
My call the extension method is 
@Html.EditButton( new { id=item.id}, "xxx")

Comment: I know. sorry, its unclear why you writing this strange code for something that you can just pass as a parameter of the method. And you could simple use `@Html.EditButton(Url.Action("Edit", "..", new { id = 123, returnUrl = ViewBag.Url }), "text")` and make the 1st parameter `string url`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I Solve I modify Marge method new code are:

```
        public static RouteValueDictionary Merge(dynamic item1, dynamic item2)
        {
            var result = new ExpandoObject();
            var d = new RouteValueDictionary();

            foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo fi in item1.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                d[fi.Name] = fi.GetValue(item1, null);

            }
            foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo fi in item2.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                d[fi.Name] = fi.GetValue(item2, null);

            }

            return d;
}
```